# Как правильно проверять уникальность вводимых данных перед занесением записи в БД?

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

В БД существует таблица, в таблице есть два поля которые должны быть уникальны.
Для этих полей создано ограничение уникальности.

Я понимаю, что проверка должна выполняться на всех уровнях путешествия данных от клиента до БД, но хотелось бы найти оптимальное решение, которое не будет требовать выполнения лишних действий, что может сказаться на производительности и устойчивости продукта.

Что лучше:

- Пропустить данные до БД и обработать exception который вернула БД ?
- Делать сначала запрос, который будет проверять, существует ли там
  такая запись?

Каким способом нужно выполнять проверку на возможность добавления данных в эту таблицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Laravel есть встроенное правило для проверки уникальности: [**`unique`**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique)

**Использование**:

```
unique:table,column,except,idColumn
```

где

- `except`: `id` записи, которая не участвует в проверке (поможет при обновлении записи)
- `idColumn`: поле, в котором хранится `id`

**Пример** для поля `email_address` таблицы `user`:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,'.$user->id.',user_id'
```

*Насколько это устраивает вас с точки зрения производительности - решать вам.*

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае я бы не заморачивался вопросами лишних действий и производительности, а подумал бы над общей логикой работы. Является ли случай записи неуникальных данных обычным делом, или это действительно исключение. Нужно ли (и как) обрабатывать такие случаи. Вы упомянули, что данные вводимые, т.е. их неуникальность вполне обычный случай + потребует каких-то дальнейших действий и оповещения стороны ввода, все это не очень вяжется с ловлей эксепшена от бд на финальный момент попытки записи, гораздо удобнее обработать все это как нам нужно и на каком нам нужно (раннем) этапе, оставив задел под будущие доработки функционала.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше так: https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation
Проверяем уникальность значения через js, до того, как отправим реальный запрос. Если валидатор выбрасывает исключения можно через тот же js уведомить.
Очень простой в использовании: https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/wiki/Basic-Usage